# why does ./ not work as a directory? [Linux]

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to install NET. 6.3 on my chromebook with Linux but when I try to execute

```bash
./dotnet-install.sh -c Current
```

in the Linux Terminal it always gives me this error:

```bash
-bash: ./dotnet-install.sh: No such file or directory
```

Any way around it/any fix for it?

I have done sudo -i so I got full permission and I have put the file I'm trying to execute in a lot of folders including my Linux folder.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `dotnet-install.sh` is either not executable or doesn't have the ["shebang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (or possibly both).

Comment: `dotnet-install.sh` is not in the current working directory. Make sure that the script is in your CWD ( $ ls dotnet-install.sh ).

Comment: If this script is a bash script, you can run it with `bash ./dotnet-install.sh`, provided that it **really** is in your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you should:

```bash
chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh
./dotnet-install.sh -c Current
```

or

```bash
/bin/bash dotnet-install.sh -c Current
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to execute a script on a UNIX/Linux platform:

- Either you make the script executable, as explained in the other answer.
- Either you use the `sh` or other relevant command for launching it, I prefer this way of working.

So, I would propose you to launch the following command:

```
sh ./dotnet-install.sh -c Current
```

Comment: Thank you for this information! It led me closer but it can't find the file for some reason. It says "sh: 0: cannot open ./dotnet-install.sh: No such file" but I have no idea where to put it?

Comment: @RestrictionBypass Where *is* the dotnet-install.sh file?

Comment: Ok so I made a bunch of copies of it because I thought I might get lucky with one of them, so there's one in my chromebooks downloads folder, one in the main area of my linux directory and one in the downloads folder of linux.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **pwd** command to see on which path are you working on? 
Then try to **ls | grep dotnet-install** in the current directory, if there isn't output you have to change directory. 
Probably you are trying to execute the **dotnet-install.sh** in a wrong directory, i suppose.

Another way is to get file trough **wget** command on terminal to be sure you download the file in the correct directory.

Regards